# Python Shell - Deleting Files Without .txt Reference

Tags: python, shell, parsing

I'm trying to write a script to check a directory of images and search a text file to see if the name shows up inside it. If the image is not referenced in the text file, I would like the script to delete the image. Here's what I have so far:

```
import os
in_gt = False
my_dir = 'C:/{...}/test'
fname = 'C:/{...}file.txt' 
for image_name in os.listdir(my_dir):
    with open(fname, 'r') as gt_file:
        for line in gt_file:
            gt_image_name = line
            if image_name in gt_image_name:
                in_gt = True
    if in_gt == False:
        os.remove(os.path.join(my_dir, fname))
```

**Additional information:** In `file.txt` each line contains an image name and then some unimportant information about the image.

**Issues:**

- Since my directory contains thousands of photos and `file.txt` contains thousands of lines, I am concerned about the efficiency of my code. I'm new to Python so I'm not confident about the speed of my script.
- Every time I run my current script, it deletes `file.txt` before actually accomplishing anything. Why is it doing this, and how do I stop it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
in_gt = False
my_dir = 'C:/{...}/test'
fname = 'C:/{...}file.txt' 
for image_name in os.listdir(my_dir):
    with open(fname, 'r') as gt_file:
        for line in gt_file:
            if image_name in line:
                in_gt = True
                break
    if in_gt == False:
        os.remove(os.path.join(my_dir, image_name))
    else:
        in_gt = False
```

answer to second problem:- 
Look at your code you are declaring variable fname in the 3th line, which is your file name called file.txt and at the of the code based on in_gt flag you are deleting fname which is nothing but 'file.txt' only

Comment: Okay, your explanation at the end makes sense; I had meant to write `image_name` instead of `fname` in that last line.

Comment: I just corrected this code to what ended up working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to reread `file.txt` for every image file in the directory. You should put file names in the directory into a set first, then when you read `file.txt`, remove all image names that appear in the file from the set, and finally delete the images whose names remain in the set.

```
import os
import re
my_dir = 'C:/{...}/test'
fname = 'C:/{...}file.txt' 
image_names = set(os.listdir(my_dir))
with open(fname, 'r') as gt_file:
    for line in gt_file:
        for name in image_names:
            if name in line:
                image_names.remove(name)
                break
for name in image_names:
    os.remove(os.path.join(my_dir, name))
```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation really cleared this up for me. For some reason, though, I keep getting the alert: `'set' object has no attribute 'replace'` even though you never use the word "replace". Do you know what's happening?

Comment: @MollyTaylor Hmm that's weird indeed. I just noticed I made a typo in my final `for` loop, where I assign image names to the variable `name` but I used `image_name` for file removal. I don't think that was the cause of the error though. I just edited my answer to fix the typo. If you still get the error after fixing this typo, feel free to edit my answer with your actual code so that I can help take a look. :-)